# Eclipse fails to create hibernate hbm.xml file

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

[image]

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                             "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-configuration>
     <session-factory name="">
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shop</property>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
      
      <mapping class="hibernate_project.cust" file="cust"
       package="hibernate_project" resource="hibernate_project/cust.hbm.xml"/>
     </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: If Eclipse does not generate the XML, what is the XML you pasted in the question?

Comment: i tried to create from the session factory so the tag is created but file doesn't.